# Error when calling Stored Procedure in Spring Boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data

I am calling a stored procedure in a Spring Boot application but when using IntelliJ IDEA it works flawlessly but when I create the Jar file and execute it, the following error appears:

```
2018-10-18 22:45:41.721  WARN 8864 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 201, SQLState: 37000
2018-10-18 22:45:41.721 ERROR 8864 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Procedure password_change_web expects parameter @id_usuario_int, which was not supplied.

2018-10-18 22:45:41.721  WARN 8864 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 201, SQLState: 37000
2018-10-18 22:45:41.721 ERROR 8864 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Procedure password_change_web expects parameter @password, which was not supplied.

2018-10-18 22:45:41.746 ERROR 8864 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [password_change_web]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Procedure password_change_web expects parameter @id_usuario_int, which was not supplied.
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE with Spring Data.

The code inside repository is:

```
@Procedure
void password_change_web(Integer idUsuarioIntranet, String password);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the required parameters @id_usuario_int, which was not supplied.? Share your code to reproduce the problem

Comment: should not the name exactly match? `idUsuarioInt` instead of `idUsuarioIntranet`?

Comment: @Barath Yes, I am sure the parameters values are not empty. The strange thing is that using the application from IntelliJ IDEA works perfect but using the Jar it gave me the error.

Comment: @Patrick I am gonna try this approach and if it works I'll let you know.

Comment: @Patrick you were right. The name of the parameter it has to be the same. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the parameters should match the right name. In your case

```
@Procedure
void password_change_web(Integer idUsuarioIntranet, String password);
```

should be changed to:

```
@Procedure
void password_change_web(Integer idUsuarioInt, String password);
```